# asp.net to have console like window on the page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to move my console application to asp.net website, where I show some action logs. What kind of control should I use for read-only actions logs? Let say on the button click I have a loop and I want to display actions from inside that loop. Should I use multiline textbox? how do I append lines? should I wrap with update panel control?

not sure which controls to pick to replicate console.log view for the website page..

Comment: If possible, I would recommend trying to look around the web to see if you can find an example of what you are trying to create. I'm having kind of a hard time envisioning what exactly you are attempting to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should google about asp.net async pages, there are many examples, you can choose one that fits your technology, for example:
[ASP.NET Asynchronous label update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271458/asp-net-asynchronous-label-update)