# Is there a way to exclude a Client from a Clients.method call in SignalR?

Tags: signalr

I am evaluating SignalR (which happens to be used with Knockoutjs) to see if we can use it to notify clients of concurrency issues.  Basically user "a" saves a record and users "b,c,d,e,f,g" are notified.  I basically have an example working that notifies all clients.  So I think I am almost there.

I came across this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872589/call-specific-client-from-signalr) and it lead me on the current path that I am on.  I have also been looking at the documentation on [Github](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs).

Basically I want to exclude the a single client from the `Clients.method()` call.  I dont see a way to loop through the clients and check the ClientId.  The only other I can see to accomplish this is to maybe look at using the groups to keep track of it, but that seemed a little cumbersome, but I was having issues with that as well.

```
 public class TicketHub : Hub
{
    static int TotalTickets = 10;

    public void GetTicketCount()
    {
        AddToGroup("ticketClients");
        Clients.setTicketCount(TotalTickets);
    }

    public void BuyTicket()
    {
        if (TotalTickets > 0)
            TotalTickets -= 1;

        RemoveFromGroup("ticketClients");

        //  This will call the method ONLY on the calling client
        //  Caller.updateTicketCountWithNotification(TotalTickets);

        // This will call the method on ALL clients in the group
        Clients["ticketClients"].updateTicketCountNotify(TotalTickets);

        AddToGroup("ticketClients");

        Caller.updateTicketCountDontNotify(TotalTickets);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you state what you want to do clearly? Do you want to show the changes that made by the user to a specific user?

Comment: @sinanakyazici To reiterate, I need to notify all clients except the caller. There doesnt seem to be a way to loop through the clients to exclude a certain one.  You can either call a specific one, or all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var test = $.connection.test;
        $("#btnTest").click(function () {
            test.testMethod();
        });
        test.show = function (text, guid) {
            if (guid != test.guid) //notify all clients except the caller
                alert(text);
        };
        $.connection.hub.start(function () { test.start(); });
    });
</script>
```

Class :

```
public class Test : Hub
{
    public void Start()
    {
        Caller.guid = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public void TestMethod()
    {
        Clients.show("test", Caller.guid);
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent.  I didnt think about managing it in the javascript.  I also  was hoping to use the client id vs. managing my own identifier. However, that works.  Thanks!

Comment: just for the record you can also use `$.connection.hub.id` instead of your own guid for something trivial like this.

Comment: Only downside to this solution is that if that message being sent to all clients is rather large, then dumping it out on the client side is   a waste of bandwidth.  In my use, mobile development, that can be a significant loss!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to exclude the caller from the call to the client side method you can use:

```
Clients.Others.clientSideMethod();
```

Comment: This assumes User a made the call to the Hub

Answer (score 3):

There is also Clients.AllExcept(...) that allows excluding certain people.

Comment: Yep, I use this now. But the version at the time of this question didnt have that call.